# JVM: Unsafe to continue after failed memory allocation?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a process that uses a library to do a time and memory consuming step that sometimes takes too much memory and throws an allocation failure on a large request. In this case, it's reasonable to accept the failure and continue processing, so my solution is to null my reference to that tool and create a new one for continued processing on following input.

Other folks in my group dispute this strategy saying that once memory has become so tight in the JVM that allocation fails, the JVM is in a suspect state: no real proof, just FUD. On the other hand, I can only argue inductively that l haven't seen ill effects yet (I haven't seen any black swans yet).

Q: Is it absolutely unsafe, and verboten to continue with a JVM that has thrown a memory allocation failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not *absolutely* unsafe.  Though it's obviously much better to avoid it if you can because who knows what sort of indeterminate state your data structures will be in after you start failing to allocate memory.

There are many applications (especially webapps) that will survive memory allocation failures very well.  However, whether it's safe or not depends to a large degree on the application.  Code that is constantly updating shared resources will degrade worse than, to use an example again, webapps that have a large degree of separation between different tasks with typically little in the way of shared resources.

The main thing is that you evaluate your application carefully and have a good idea about the pitfalls you may run into.  That, and try to restart the JVM as soon as possible after the failure. ;)

Comment: I can't avoid it because the library is 3rd party, and I can't modify it. The relevant data structures are all in that library and by dropping the parser (the thing in the library) and creating a new one, I am, in effect, re-setting that part of the app.

My question, perhaps worthy of an edit to clarify, regards the continued viability of the JVM itself after such an event.

Comment: Well, the JVM in and of itself should be fine.  That's the reason it tosses out the OOME instead of just stopping.  It believes itself to be able to keep on truckin'.  But of course, data structures can be left in indeterminate states.  So that's why it becomes a value judgement based on careful evaluation of your app.

Comment: This has been my thinking. Some references to help fight the FUD in an academic environment would help. thanks.

Comment: Sorry...I don't have any docs that I can immediately pass off.  You can poke around with the JLS http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html.  It's interesting to note that even an assignment can cause OOME if it needs to auto-unboxing and there's no space left.

Answer (score 1):

When you run out of memory, other threads can also run out of memory and they may not handle this so gracefully.  You may find you can continue most of the time, but it is better not to run out of memory in the first place.